# Don't use backcolor on a label but still use a background from its parent

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Assume that I have a panel, this panel has a background image. I add a label to this panel. Anyone can help me how to show label's text but don't show label's backcolor, the label will inherit background image from its parent. I use a transparent backcolor on label but not effect.

**Note:** WinForm.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a transparent background color should work.

Note that the windows forms designer doesn't honor transparency, but at runtime it should displayed as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you use the Web.Transparent color, it tends to work better.

Select your label and go to it's Properties > Backcolor > Click the Web tab > Transparent.

If you need more specific directions, please ask.

Comment: This works better than what? If I remember correctly, the Web tab *is* where the "Transparent" color is located in Visual Studio.

Comment: Works better than setting it in the code behind. Don't ask me why, but if you set `Lbl1.BackColor = Color.Transparent` or whatever the syntax is, it wont work. However, if you set it in designer view under the Web tab, it seems to work fine, regardless of whether it is running or in designer.

Comment: That is, of course, not possible. Setting it in the designer simply sets it in the `*.cs.designer` file corresponding to your form class, the exact equivalent to you setting it in your form's constructor. It *does* make sense that setting it in the designer might make the transparency effect visible at design time--the designer doesn't run the code in your form's constructor in order to display it in the designer, so the fact that you've set the `BackColor` gets ignored. If you set it in the designer, the control is immediately updated.

Comment: My only thought would be that Color.Transparent does not correspond to whatever color property is being selected when you choose Transparent under the Web tab. However, I have not investigated this, only seen the results and noted a discrepancy.